# Pulling in a valid json file to a Backbone.js collection results in an error

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

When I try to fetch the collection, I get nothing and the error clause on my fetch request is triggered. This is what my collection and model looks like:

```
window.Codetest.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        id: null,
        userId: null,
        date: null,
        content: null,
        comments: []
    }
});


window.Codetest.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "posts.json",
    model: Codetest.Models.Post
});

Codetest.Collections.posts = new Codetest.Collections.Posts();
Codetest.Collections.posts.fetch({
success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(){
     console.log('error');
  } 
});
```

I am pulling in posts that look like this from a posts.json file which is in the same directory as my javascript file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "date": "",
        "content":"Love wine? Love food? Love to win an iPad 2 with gift certificates to your favorite IA winery & Dine IA restaurant. http://bit.ly/xQ4Ls8",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "postId": 1,
                "userId": 3,
                "date": "",
                "content": "Would you happen to know were Capone is? Since you are a secret agent and all"
            }

        ]

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "userId": 3,
        "date": "",
        "content":"Day 2 of house sitting...awww my firends really do Trust me!",
        "comments": []

    }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an http sever to serve the file? Does getting the file in your browser work?

Answer (score 0):

If the posts.json file is in the same directory, then use the following:

```
window.Codetest.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/posts.json",
    model: Codetest.Models.Post
});
```

You need to add the " / " in order for it to fetch properly.